# SVG <image> element created in JS does not display

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I have an `<svg>` element (with `viewBox` set) and I append a programmatically constructed `<image>` element to it, like this:

```js
const img=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
img.setAttribute('width','100');
img.setAttribute('height','100');
img.setAttribute('xlink:href','data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA'+
'ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4'+
'//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU'+
'5ErkJggg==');
document.querySelector('svg').appendChild(img);
```

It is present in the SVG but nothing is displayed. However when I call `img.outerHTML = img.outerHTML;` to sort of recreate it from its text representation, it starts displaying properly.

Anyone could help me understand what's going on? How should I create the element in JS to make it display properly?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rj9eaoq/8/)

Comment: Does the SVG tag itself not need a width and a height?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything, you can easily see it in the fiddle. Without size the SVG just takes 100% of body, but it's definitely there.

Comment: no other solution than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SVG-2 ready browsers you can simply do `setAttribute("href", url)`.

However, in SVG-1.x you must use `setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);`

Actually with `setAttributeNS`, you can also use `'xlink:href'` for the second parameter or `'foo:href'`, since `setAttributeNS` takes care of mapping to the correct NameSpace and kind of discards what comes before `:`, but `setAttribute` doesn't and thus creates a kind of `null:xlink:href` attribute, which doesn't map to anything known by the browser and thus fails.

```js
const url = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
const img =  document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');

img.setAttribute('width','100');
img.setAttribute('height','100');

img.setAttribute('href', url); // SVG-2
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', url); // SVG-1.x

document.querySelector('svg').appendChild(img);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
```